# Passing data from Excel to a Web service

Tags: java, web-services

I have a excel file with testing data and am trying to send these parameters to a new web service (Testing) in java. These data will inturn be sent to another web service that is already in use now. After sending the request data, I will also need to get the response and update the excel file with the testing result ,say pass or fail. I haven't worked with web services(java) before , so am not sure how to go about this. Any tutorials or advice on this from people who have worked on this before will be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hope you have worked with Java before because this is not a straightforward assignment.

You will need an API to read the Excel spreadsheet ( look up JXL or Apache POI ), you will need to generate a web services client for your WS endpoint using JAX-WS ( wsimport ). Once you have that, you can call your web service via Java and the response will be a Java object that you can then use to update your Excel sheet ( via the api of your choice ).

Good luck.

http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html

http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html

Comment: yes I have worked with java before and have worked with accessing excel through asp. So I am cnfident with accessing excel data through java. But the thing I need more info on is for the webservice part. Could you provide more information on learning the web services part?